# Accessing Java Bean Properties by Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp

I have some Java beans that I am trying to use in a JSP:

```
class Review{
    int id;
    String text;
    User author;
    // ... getters/setters here ...
}

class User{
    int id;   
    boolean isVisitor;  
    // ... getters/setters here ...   
}

class VisitorUser extends User{
    String name;
    // ... getters/setters here ...
}
```

There is a bean of type Review that I am trying to access in EL:

```
${review.author.name}
```

As you can see, `author` in the review is of type `User` and the name property I am trying to access in the EL belongs to its subclass `VisitorUser`. Is this approach correct for EL when author is an instance of `VisitorUser`?

This approach worked well before, but suddenly out of nowhere (or probably as a side-effect of some changes in some other areas of the project), server has begun to give this error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: Unable to find a value for "name" in object of class "mypackage.domain.User_$$_javassist_27" using operator "."
```

Any hint/idea/link to solve this error will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. It inspects the object at runtime. But your object is not of type `VisitorUser`, but of javassist-enhanced `User` instead. So make sure you have the right object.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Bozho. By the way, I am using Hibernate in my project which requires javassist.

Comment: @craftsman - I see. then, are you sure you have a `VisitorUser`. It might be just `User` (perhaps you haven't correctly mapped your hibernate inheritance)

Comment: Mapping is correct. I am sure about that because same Reviews are being displayed correctly in another JSP. The specific JSP causing problem is supposed to show Activities (another persistent entity) and Reviews. Now Activity is entirely another entity unlinked to Review, but strangely when I fetch Activities from database, I get the above EL error (with Activities shown correctly and Reviews causing problem). And when I remove Activities, Reviews again began to appear correctly.